# angular js $http call returns object object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am trying to get data from my database via angular factory, The following is my code

```
if (!$scope.isNew) {
    productsService
        .readProduct($routeParams.id)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("data in edit " + data);
            $scope.person = data;
        });
}
```

In my product service I have given the following code

```
  readProduct: function (productId) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/api/products/' + productId
                }).success(function (data) {
                    alert("success in read");
                    console.log(data);

                }).error(function (error) {
                    //Showing error message 
                    alert("failed");
                    $scope.status = 'Unable to retrieve products' + error.message;
                });
            },
```

I am getting the alert success in read and in console I am getting the data. But where I have called the function I am not getting the data. ie in my console I am getting "data in edit object Object".

Comment: try `console.log((JSON.stringify(data));` to see the object content.

Comment: @Aniket no luck :( still showing as object

Comment: @AniketSinha I cleared cache n its working in console now..but still its not binding to my view..

Comment: show me your view code? and what does the HTTP GET returns? an array or a single object?

Comment: what is the value received in `.success` of `readProduct ` ? what is the output in console there?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you need to `return data;` in your `.success` callback in your service:

```
.success(function (data) {
     alert("success in read");
     console.log(data);
     return data;
}
```